# Redirects not working properly HTACCESS HTML website

Tags: html, .htaccess

Currently i am redirecting from my website: Columbusperfectionlasers.com (HTML) to Columbuslasikvision.com (Wordpress) I have all pages being redirected on the .htaccess file as follow:

```
Redirect 301 / https://www.columbuslasikvision.com/
Redirect 301 /financing https://www.columbuslasikvision.com/financing/
```

These 2 work ok but the following redirects to a different page:

```
Redirect 301 /procedures/lasik https://www.columbuslasikvision.com/about-lasik/
```

This one redirects to another page which is: https://www.columbuslasikvision.com/lasik-faqs/ which is wrong. it should go to **about-lasik** page.

I've tested with several redirection checker tools and this is what i get:

[image]

I attached my .htaccess here so you can see what am i doing wrong. Thanks for the help.

```
Redirect 301 /procedures/lasik https://www.columbuslasikvision.com/about-lasik/


Redirect 301 / https://www.columbuslasikvision.com/
Redirect 301 /financing https://www.columbuslasikvision.com/financing/
Redirect 301 /blog/ https://www.columbuslasikvision.com/blog/
Redirect 301 /locations https://www.columbuslasikvision.com/locations/
Redirect 301 /video https://www.columbuslasikvision.com/videos/
Redirect 301 /procedures https://www.columbuslasikvision.com/laser-technologies/
Redirect 301 /procedures/lahayesik https://www.columbuslasikvision.com/laser-technologies/
Redirect 301 /financing/cost https://www.columbuslasikvision.com/pricing/
Redirect 301 /site-map https://www.columbuslasikvision.com/sitemap/
Redirect 301 /contact-lasik https://www.columbuslasikvision.com/contact/
Redirect 301 /our-doctors https://www.columbuslasikvision.com/our-doctors/
Redirect 301 /procedures/prk https://www.columbuslasikvision.com/prk/
Redirect 301 /blog?page=2 https://www.columbuslasikvision.com/blog/
Redirect 301 /blog?page=4 https://www.columbuslasikvision.com/blog/
Redirect 301 /why-choose/servingallentownpa https://www.columbuslasikvision.com/allentown/
Redirect 301 /procedures/custom-lasik https://www.columbuslasikvision.com/custom-lasik/
Redirect 301 /blog?p=101 https://www.columbuslasikvision.com/blog/
Redirect 301 /video/player?category_id=1397 https://www.columbuslasikvision.com/videos/
Redirect 301 /video/player/26850-lahayesik https://www.columbuslasikvision.com/videos/
Redirect 301 /locations/feasterville-trevose-pa https://www.columbuslasikvision.com/philadelphia/
Redirect 301 /patient-testimonials/staff-testimonials https://www.columbuslasikvision.com/testimonials/
Redirect 301 /why-choose/areasservedintri-state https://www.columbuslasikvision.com/why-choose-us/
Redirect 301 /locations/wilkes-barre-pa https://www.columbuslasikvision.com/wilkes-barre/
Redirect 301 /video/player?category_id=1400 https://www.columbuslasikvision.com/videos/
Redirect 301 /video/59635-jessica-s-story https://www.columbuslasikvision.com/videos/
Redirect 301 /video/59563-jill-s-story https://www.columbuslasikvision.com/videos/
Redirect 301 /video/59573-brian-s-story https://www.columbuslasikvision.com/videos/
Redirect 301 /video/59403-jessica-s-story https://www.columbuslasikvision.com/videos/
Redirect 301 /video/59507-adriano-s-story https://www.columbuslasikvision.com/videos/
Redirect 301 /video/player/7364-marys-testimony https://www.columbuslasikvision.com/videos/
Redirect 301 /video/player/59397-dallas-story https://www.columbuslasikvision.com/videos/
Redirect 301 /video/59405-johnathan-s-story
```

Answer (score 0):

Apache server successfully permanently redirects `https://columbusperfectionlasers.com/procedures/lasik` to `https://www.columbuslasikvision.com/procedures/lasik` and then Nginx server permanently redirects further to `https://www.columbuslasikvision.com/lasik-faqs/` there you get the end page.

**The problem is on Nginx redirect rules.**

```
>>> https://columbusperfectionlasers.com/procedures/lasik

> --------------------------------------------
> 301 Moved Permanently
> --------------------------------------------

Status: 301 Moved Permanently
Code:   301
Date:   Wed, 14 Aug 2019 16:18:27 GMT
Server: Apache
Location:   https://www.columbuslasikvision.com/procedures/lasik
Content-Length: 260
Connection: close
Content-Type:   text/html; charset=iso-8859-1




>>> https://www.columbuslasikvision.com/procedures/lasik

> --------------------------------------------
> 301 Moved Permanently
> --------------------------------------------

Status: 301 Moved Permanently
Code:   301
Server: nginx
Date:   Wed, 14 Aug 2019 16:18:27 GMT
Content-Type:   text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Expires:    Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
X-Redirect-By:  WordPress
Location:   https://www.columbuslasikvision.com/lasik-faqs/
WPE-Backend:    apache
X-Cacheable:    non200
Cache-Control:  max-age=600, must-revalidate
X-Cache:    HIT: 1
X-Pass-Why: 
X-Cache-Group:  normal




>>> https://www.columbuslasikvision.com/lasik-faqs/

> --------------------------------------------
> 200 OK
> --------------------------------------------

Status: 200 OK
Code:   200
Server: nginx
Date:   Wed, 14 Aug 2019 16:18:28 GMT
Content-Type:   text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 124564
Connection: close
Vary:   Accept-Encoding,Cookie
Link:   <https://www.columbuslasikvision.com/?p=2337>; rel=shortlink
WPE-Backend:    apache
X-Cacheable:    SHORT
Cache-Control:  max-age=600, must-revalidate
X-Cache:    HIT: 14
X-Pass-Why: 
X-Cache-Group:  normal
Accept-Ranges:  bytes
```